# How to recognise the type of allele by pedigree analysis diagrams?

Tags: genetics, homework, allele, genetic-diagrams, pedigree

[image]

It was said that this interference pattern is due to dominant allele. I fail to see that.
In general how to recognise the type of allele by pedigree analysis diagrams?

Answer (score 1):

This question is a bit broad. You have to understand a lot of concepts to figure out the nature of the allele. I'll just point out some basics:

1. If an allele is dominant it should affect both males and females equally (not X-linked)
2. If one of the parents shows the trait (while other does not) then at least one offspring should show the trait (basic Mendelian segregation)
3. If both parents show the trait and one of the offspring does not then it means that the parents are heterozygous and the allele is dominant.